# Navbar-toggle button for my hamburger menu doesnt show up on tablets

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

im really new to the bootstrap web programming and im trying to teach myself this amazing type of website design, while working on my recent project I have run into a problem. I have 2 different master pages, 1 for any computer/laptop and one for Phones/tablets (this is mainly to alter the way the menu is displayed) now, the problem I have is that the hamburger menu doesn't show up while using a tablet but it does while using any mobile device. below is a link to a code snippet and also the HTML part of my code, I am using the basic bootstrap CSS you can download 7000 lines long so I wont link it. any help or advice will be amazing.

Thank you!

http://www.codeply.com/go/chZdZeh85V

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button  class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>


            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse fullscreen-navbar-collapse">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HomeLV" runat="server">
                    <RoleGroups>
                        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Masters, Administrators, General Managers, Support Workers, Managers">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div id="MainMenu10">
                                    <div class="list-group panel">
                                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" href="../../../../default.aspx" data-parent="#MainMenu10">Home  </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:RoleGroup>
                    </RoleGroups>
                </asp:LoginView>


                <asp:LoginView ID="AddressLV" runat="server">
                    <RoleGroups>
                        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Masters, General Managers, Support Workers, Senior Workers, Managers">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div id="MainMenu11">
                                    <div class="list-group panel">
                                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" href="../../../../Homes/Address_Book/Address_Book.aspx" data-parent="#MainMenu11">Address Book  </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:RoleGroup>
                    </RoleGroups>
                </asp:LoginView>

                <asp:LoginView ID="SysAdminLV" runat="server">
                    <RoleGroups>
                        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Masters">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div id="MainMenu5">
                                    <div class="list-group panel">
                                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" href="#demo7" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu5">+  System Admin  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                                        <div class="collapse" id="demo7">
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/Masters/Manage_Users.aspx" data-parent="#MainMenu5">Manage User</a>
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/Masters/New_User.aspx" data-parent="#MainMenu5">New User</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:RoleGroup>
                    </RoleGroups>
                </asp:LoginView>

                <asp:LoginView ID="HouseLV" runat="server">
                    <RoleGroups>
                        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Masters, General Managers, Managers, Support Workers, Senior Workers, Administrators">
                            <ContentTemplate>

                                <div id="MainMenu4">
                                    <div class="list-group panel">
                                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" href="#demo6" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu4">+  House files  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                                        <div class="collapse" id="demo6">
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../Homes/Calendar/Home_Calendar.aspx" data-parent="#MainMenu4">Home Calendar</a>
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Homes/Appliances/View_Fridge_Temp.aspx" data-parent="#MainMenu4">Fridge Tempatures</a>
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Homes/Appliances/View_Freezer_Temp.aspx" data-parent="#MainMenu4">Freezer Tempatures</a>
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Homes/Document_Forms/View_Hsome_Documents.aspx" data-parent="#MainMenu4">Home Documents</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:RoleGroup>
                    </RoleGroups>
                </asp:LoginView>


                <asp:LoginView ID="GeneralMLV" runat="server">
                    <RoleGroups>
                        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Masters, General Managers">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div id="MainMenu1">
                                    <div class="list-group panel">
                                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" href="#demo10" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu1">+  General Manager  </a>
                                        <div class="collapse" id="demo10">
                                            <a class="list-group-item1" href="#Homes" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Homes">+  Homes</a>
                                            <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="Homes">
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/General_Managers/New_Homes_Wizard.aspx" data-parent="#Homes">Create New Homes</a>
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/General_Managers/Edit_Homes.aspx" data-parent="#Homes">Edit Homes</a>
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/General_Managers/Edit_Home_Viewers.aspx" data-parent="#Homes">Edit Home Viewers</a>
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Homes/Vacancies/Home_Vacancies.aspx" data-parent="#Homes">Edit Home Vacancies</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <a class="list-group-item1" href="#Post" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Post">+  Post</a>
                                            <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="Post">
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/Group/Posts/Edit_Post.aspx" data-parent="#Post">View Post</a>
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/Group/Posts/New_Post.aspx" data-parent="#Post">New Post</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:RoleGroup>
                    </RoleGroups>
                </asp:LoginView>

                <asp:LoginView ID="AdministrationLV" runat="server">
                    <RoleGroups>
                        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Masters, General Managers, Administrators, Managers">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div id="MainMenu3">
                                    <div class="list-group panel">
                                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" href="#demo3" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu3">+  Administration  </a>
                                        <div class="collapse" id="demo3">
                                            <a class="list-group-item1" href="#Appliances" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Appliances">+  Appliances</a>
                                            <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="Appliances">
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Homes/Appliances/Fridge.aspx" data-parent="#Appliances">Fridge</a>
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Homes/Appliances/Freezers.aspx" data-parent="#Appliances">Freezer</a>
                                            </div>

                                            <div id="list-group panel">
                                                <a class="list-group-item1" href="../../../General/Authorities/Authorities.aspx" data-parent="#Mainmenu3">Authorities</a>
                                            </div>

                                            <a class="list-group-item1" href="#Backgrounds" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Backgrounds">+  Backgrounds</a>
                                            <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="Backgrounds">
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../General/Religions/Religions.aspx" data-parent="#Backgrounds">Relegion</a>
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../General/Ethnicities/Ethnicities.aspx" data-parent="#Backgrounds">Ethnicities</a>
                                            </div>


                                            <a class="list-group-item1" href="#Placements" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Placements">+  Placements</a>
                                            <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="Placements">
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/Placements/New_Referral.aspx" data-parent="#Placements">New placement</a>
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/Placements/End_Referral.aspx" data-parent="#Placements">End Placement</a>
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/Placements/New_Placement.aspx" data-parent="#Placements">New Referal</a>
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/Placements/End_Placement.aspx" data-parent="#Placements">End Referal</a>
                                            </div>

                                            <a class="list-group-item1" href="#Education" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Education">+  Education</a>
                                            <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="Education">
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../General/Education/Schools.aspx" data-parent="#Education">Schools</a>
                                            </div>

                                            <a class="list-group-item1" href="#PoliciesDoc" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#PoliciesDoc">+  Policies/Documents  </a>
                                            <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="PoliciesDoc">
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Homes/Document_Forms/Document_Types.aspx" data-parent="#PoliciesDoc">Add/Edit Documents</a>
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Homes/Document_Forms/Upload_Home_Document.aspx" data-parent="#PoliciesDoc">Update House Documents</a>
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/Group/Group_Document_Forms/New_Group_Template.aspx" data-parent="#PoliciesDoc">Update Group Template</a>
                                                <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Staff/Group/Group_Document_Forms/New_Group_Policy.aspx" data-parent="#PoliciesDoc">Update Group Policy</a>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:RoleGroup>
                    </RoleGroups>
                </asp:LoginView>

                <asp:LoginView ID="ChildLV" runat="server">
                    <RoleGroups>
                        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Masters, General Managers, Administrators, Support Workers, Managers">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div id="MainMenu12">
                                    <div class="list-group panel">
                                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" href="#Childdetails" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu12">+  Child Details</a>
                                        <div class="collapse" id="Childdetails">
                                            <a class="list-group-item2" href="../../../../Records/Forms/Search_Children.aspx" data-parent="#Childdetails">Search Child Details</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:RoleGroup>
                    </RoleGroups>
                </asp:LoginView>


                <asp:LoginView ID="TemplateLV" runat="server">
                    <RoleGroups>
                        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Masters, General Managers, Administrators, Support Workers, Managers">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div id="MainMenu13">
                                    <div class="list-group panel">
                                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" href="../../../../Staff/Group/Group_Document_Forms/View_Group_Templates.aspx" data-parent="#MainMenu13">Group Templates</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:RoleGroup>
                    </RoleGroups>
                </asp:LoginView>

                <asp:LoginView ID="PoliciesLV" runat="server">
                    <RoleGroups>
                        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Masters, General Managers, Administrators, Support Workers, Managers">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div id="MainMenu14">
                                    <div class="list-group panel">
                                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-success" href="../../../../Staff/Group/Group_Document_Forms/View_Group_Policies.aspx" data-parent="#MainMenu14">Group Policies</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:RoleGroup>
                    </RoleGroups>
                </asp:LoginView>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                            <AnonymousTemplate>
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li><a href="~/Account/Login" runat="server">Log in</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </AnonymousTemplate>
                            <LoggedInTemplate>
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li>
                                        <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" LogoutPageUrl="~/" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutAction="Redirect"></asp:LoginStatus>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </LoggedInTemplate>
                        </asp:LoginView>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap by default will hide your navbar-toggle at a media width of more than 768px. I'd recommend adding a class to your navbar-toggle such as `.hidden-md`

Take a look at the bootstrap documentation here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons and look under responsive utilities. You could also remove or overwrite the following line in the Bootstrap CSS file

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Working example of the over written CSS here http://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/pen/677b30cdd86fdc14abfde5df8c983053

Comment: tried that and it didn't change anything. I added the Navbar part of my CSS onto the site I send you and all I get is an application error lol!

Comment: The site doesn't work for me either for some reason which is why i went with Codepen. I'm not sure how Codeply works so i can't really help with that. Have you changed the CSS on a local copy of the site?

Comment: yeah I changed the code on Visual studio on my computer then published it over my network through IIS and tried it on my tablet and still not showing up.

Comment: Are you sure its not just hidden behind the green blocks? Try adding .navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
    margin-top: 70px;
}

Comment: Hi Jamie, I have tried to add your suggested code to my CSS and it made no change, it seems that the hamburger menu just isn't showing up at all. have you got any other suggestions?

Comment: Jamie, here is my full code if its helpful?https://codepen.io/bennickless/pen/dMrzEV

Comment: Line 4377. As explained in my answer remove this line. @media (min-width: 768px)
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
}
https://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/pen/RadLWJ?editors=0110

Comment: I have just removed the class as suggested and then published it and still no hamburger menu on my Ipad. Im really not sure what happening here.

Comment: Have you viewed the Codepen link? Does it work for you on desktop when you change the width of the window to above 768px? What tablet do you have?

Comment: yeah, I looked at the codepen link and everything seemed fine. it worked on my desktop and its an Ipad2.